# Drools dialect difference between implicit and explicit conjunction (AND)

Tags: java, drools, implicit

In drools the drools dialect, conjunctions are implicit. For example:

```
rule "new drool"
when
Fact(id=="fact1")
Fact(id=="fact2")
then
end
```

The above requires there be two Fact objects. One must have an id of "fact1", the other must have an id of "fact2".

However, the AND operator does exist. You could write the same drools as follows:

```
rule "new drool"
when
Fact(id=="fact1") AND
Fact(id=="fact2")
then
end
```

I was under the impression that there is absolutely no logical or practical difference between these two expressions. However, I have a user telling me he is experiencing different behavior when he uses the explicit conjunction vs the implicit one. I am skeptical, but I haven't been able to find any documentation to support my position. Does anyone know whether an implicit vs explicit conjunction in drools could see different behavior?

Comment: What behaviour difference he is experiencing ?

Comment: He has a when clause with two objects, much like the example above. Apparently, using the implicit conjunction, the rule does not fire. Using the explicit conjunction, it does. I cannot actually confirm this behavior as I am not experiencing it myself. I am less interested in trying to debug that here than I am in finding an answer to whether there is a difference between implicit and explicit AND in drools.

Comment: I dont see any difference in above two infact I just ran a test case to reconfirm above, only one small this AND should be in small case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AND is implicit between the two Conditional Elements, so if the user is experiencing different behaviours there should be a bug there. If you can manage to reproduce in a test case the different behaviours please open a jira for it.

Comment: Thank you saladboy. I'll try to reproduce his behavior and, if it exists, I will open a ticket.